# How do I create a frame (possibly iframe) in the entire right half of the user's screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frames

I have normal code written right now using Bootstrap. 
I want the **easiest** way to create a frame that fills 40% of the entire user's right screen.

I've looked into frameset, but I'm not sure if that's the easiest way to do it inside current bootstrap code.

```
<frameset cols="30%,50%">
<frame src="page1.htm">
<frame src="page2.htm">
</frameset>
```

Comment: the `html.iframe`-tag should do the trick? Setting it to `css.width:40%`. You could use `css.float:right` for this frame. And do `css.float:left` for the other.. Or you could just set the two of them to `css.display:inline-block; css.vertical-align:top;`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

body {
position: relative;
}

frame {
position:absolute;
width: 50%;
top:0%;
left:50%;
}
```